# import error in python on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created my first python module on ubuntu. When I'm trying to import the module in python using :

```
import brian
```

it is giving error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named brian
```

I have `brian` in `/home/noamaan` and python is in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Are you running python in the same directory as the module file? Is the file called `brain.py`?

Comment: Where are you running your python file from?

Comment: Open a terminal window; type `cd` and hit enter, now type `python` and hit enter, and type `import brian` at the Python prompt `>>>` and hit enter; do you get an error?

Answer (score 3):

If you launch **python** from the directory that contains *brian* module, everything will work as it is now.

To import custom module **from anywhere you want** you should read attentively something on the import mechanism in python to learn where the imported modules are searched for, etc.

But to make your code work right now, I can recommend you the following:

- Either extend your **PYTHONPATH** variable before running python, to include the directory of your module
- Or append it right in the code by using **sys** module in this way.

  > ```
  > import sys
  >
  > sys.path.append("path/to/module/dir")
  >
  > import brian
  > ```

Also, see info on [site](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/site.html#module-site) module

Comment: Or you can just run `python` from the directory containing the file.

Comment: Surely, but I didn't regard is a solution. Added to my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

by default Python import modules from Python path var.
You can view these paths so:

> import sys
>
> print sys.path